# Ionic - HTML list with parents and child elements

Tags: ionic-framework, parent, children, items, ion-list

I have data in `array` where every element represents parent object, and every parent object has `items` array, whose elements are children. I have to generate on HTML parents list + nested children list under every parent. Every child element is clickable (navigates to another page). Something like on image. Any help here? I can use *ngFor to iterate first level elements (parents) and use `ion-list` and `ion-item` but how to nest children?

[image]

Comment: Show you data which are going to execute in ngFor.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do a nested `*ngFor`.

**Example data:**

```
var categories = [
    {
        "name": "Category 1",
        "items": [
            "item1"
            "item2"
        ]
    }
];
```

**Example template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of category.items">{{item}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

At the top-level you iterate your **categories**, and for every single category, you iterate its **items**.